# Xcode Swift Query createdAt from Parse and show in label

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform

Im trying to query createdAt date from Parse and show the date in tableview cell, but the tableview are showing the date from other row in Parse.

My code are:

```
func queryParse() {

    let query1 = PFQuery(className: "Lokation")
    query1.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects : [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {

                let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

                self.mainArray.append(object)
                self.dateCreated = object["Dato"] as! NSDate

                let DateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.dateCreated)
                self.dateCreatedOut = DateInFormat

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you call self.tableView.reloadData() two times?

Comment: Thats a fault, but it dit not effect the problem